# $dateFromString will this convert month name to number using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which is have expected date is string format "19-Sep-2019". How can I write an aggregate query based on expected date match.
Below is my collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe7718733e"),
    "project_name" : "p1",
    "expected" : "19-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "19-Sep-2019"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340"),
    "project_name" : "p2",
    "expected" : "20-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "20-Sep-2019"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187342"),
    "project_name" : "p3",
    "expected" : "19-Jan-2020",
    "actual" : "19-Jan-2020"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187344"),
    "project_name" : "p4",
    "expected" : "20-Jan-2020",
    "actual" : "20-Jan-2020"
}
```

I need to write a query like below. But its fetching all the values. How can I use $dateFromString for this purpose?

```
db.getCollection('test2').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"expected":{"$gte":"01-Sep-2019","$lte":"30-Sep-2019"}}}
 ])
```

Expected  result is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe7718733e"),
    "project_name" : "p1",
    "expected" : "19-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "19-Sep-2019"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340"),
    "project_name" : "p2",
    "expected" : "20-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "20-Sep-2019"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `$dateFromString` does not support `MMM` abbreviation pattern

**Workaround 1:** We create array with month's names ("Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec") and with [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) we get array index equivalent to month + [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/index.html) operator we create `ISODate`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      months: [
        "",
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: {
            $toInt: {
              $substr: [
                "$expected",
                7,
                4
              ]
            }
          },
          month: {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$months",
              {
                $substr: [
                  "$expected",
                  3,
                  3
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          day: {
            $toInt: {
              $substr: [
                "$expected",
                0,
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: ISODate("2019-09-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2019-09-30")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "months",
      "date"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RihWZ5axen9)

**Workaround 2:** You need to use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator to transform months: `Jan` - 1, `Feb` - 2 ... `Sep` - 9 and with [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/index.html) operator  we create `ISODate`.

```
{
   $switch: {
      branches: [
         { case: { $eq: [ "Jan", {$substr:["$expected", 3, 3]} ] }, then: 1 },
         { case: { $eq: [ "Feb", {$substr:["$expected", 3, 3]} ] }, then: 2 },
         { case: { $eq: [ "Sep", {$substr:["$expected", 3, 3]} ] }, then: 9 },
         { case: { $eq: [ "Dec", {$substr:["$expected", 3, 3]} ] }, then: 12 }
      ],
      default: null
   }
}
```

---

```
db.test2.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{
    date : {$dateFromParts:{
      year: {$toInt: {$substring:["$expected",7,4]} },
      month: {$toInt: {$switch:{...}} },
      day: {$toInt: {$substring:["$expected",0,2]} },
    }}
  }},
  {"$match":{"date ":{"$gte":ISODate("2019-09-01"),"$lte":ISODate("2019-09-30")}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation can be used to match the `expected` date string.

Consider the *input documents*:

```
{ "expected" : "20-Jan-2020" }
{ "expected" : "10-Feb-2020" }
```

*The query:*

```
MONTHS_ARR = [ "Jan01", "Feb02", "Mar03" ]    // [TODO] "Apr04", ..., "Dec12"

db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
    $addFields: {  
        expected: { 
            $concat: [ 
                { $substrCP: [ "$expected", 7, 4 ] }, 
                 "-", 
                 { $reduce: {
                        input: MONTHS_ARR, initialValue: "",
                        in: {
                            $substrCP: [
                                { $arrayElemAt: [ 
                                       { $filter: {
                                              input: MONTHS_ARR, as: "mm",
                                              cond: {
                                                   $eq: [ { $substrCP: [ "$$mm", 0, 3 ] },  { $substrCP: [ "$expected", 3, 3 ] } ]
                                              }
                                        } },
                                0 ] },
                            3, 2 ]
                        }
                 } }, 
                 "-", 
                 { $substrCP: [ "$expected", 0, 2 ] } 
            ]
        } 
  } },
  {
      $match: { expected: { $gte: "2020-01-15", $lte: "2020-02-06" } }
  }
] )
```

The *result*  document:  `{ "expected" : "2020-01-20" }`